# What did Carl Jung mean by "subjectivization of consciousness"?

Tags: jung

I am reading "Psychological Types" by Carl Jung and I came across this sentence:

> But it is a characteristic peculiarity of the introvert, which is as much in keeping with his own inclination as with the general bias, to confuse his ego with the self, and to exalt it as the subject of the psychic process, thus bringing about the aforementioned subjectivization of consciousness which alienates him from the object.

At this sentence, what I didn't understand is what is "subjectivization of consciousness" and how does it cause alienation from object?

I would be glad if someone can explain.

Comment: Whilst [I am a defender of Freudian and Neo-Freudian psychology](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248), please be aware that this covers areas of psychology [considered by some here to be pseudoscientific](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing Jung’s [nature of objects](https://carljungdepthpsychologysite.blog/2018/06/29/carl-jung-on-the-nature-of-objects/) the object for which the introvert becomes alienated is the item, topic, or nature that is causing a subjective reaction. This in keeping with the struggle of maintaining a proper distinction between the self and ego creates a confusion toward which is “steering the ship” so to speak. That is to say which is the

> perceived subject of the psychic process

This subjective experience of consciousness causes a withdrawal from the “object” in question.

I like to think of this withdrawal as a form of [cognitive dissonance](https://www.simplypsychology.org/cognitive-dissonance.html)  as the inconsistency between what is expected to be felt or perceived as the correct feeling versus what the actual feeling toward the object is, causes mental discomfort changing the perceived attitude towards the object. This is a loose association but allows some abstraction towards the question at hand.

Comment: The object can be a person too.

Comment: Absolutely! Maybe a noun would be a better label?